# How to add a control abline - different for different plots?

Tags: r, string, sorting, statistics

I have a large data set giving data on multiple parameters for a number of treatments, one of them being control.

I have written a script that allows me to generate multiple scatter plots of treatment$parameter, and am now looking to add in an abline(h="control") but I keep getting an error.

"control" is one of many treatments and in the data set is under the "treatments" column. Am I incorporating it wrong?

I tried abline(h=treatment=="control") but no luck. Also any advice on how to be thinking about these - I wan't to call them translation issues - would be very much appreciated and would help me on my journey of self-troubleshooting.

Edit:

As an example: for data("USArrests")
My script already generates scatter plots for all the columns (murder, assault etc.; and for my data frame there are several data points/parameter). If I were trying to do a similar thing with USArrests, I'd want a benchmark line at California$Parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you write `abline(h=SOMETHING)` SOMETHING has to evaluate to a number. If your control is a constant, you could use something like `abline(h=treatment$control[1])`.  If it is not a constant,  I am unclear what line you want to draw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `abline(h="control")`or `abline(h=treatment=="control")` , it doesn't work because the first is trying to plot a character and second, a boolean. The abline(h=..) needs a numeric input.

Since you which row the abline is coming from, you can do:

```
library(datasets)
wh = which(rownames(USArrests)=="California")
```

If you use pairs, you can plot like this:

```
plotfun = function(x,y){
points(x,y,pch=18);abline(h=y[wh],lty=8,col="blue")
}
pairs(USArrests,upper.panel=NULL,panel=plotfun)
```

[image]

If you have a for loop:

```
PAIRS = combn(colnames(USArrests),2)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
for(i in 1:ncol(PAIRS)){
plot(USArrests[,PAIRS[,i]])
INTERCEPT = USArrests[wh,PAIRS[2,i]]
abline(h=INTERCEPT,lty=8,col="blue")
}
```

[image]